# CI 2 vs 3 differences with post data already seems to be url decoded already

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following code that displays a simple form and posts it and CI 2 seems to already have url decoded the data before I decode it; so it gets double decoded. This only happens in CI 2. Is there a way to get this to work without using $_REQUEST?

Here is the code and output

```
function test()
{
        if ($this->input->post('test'))
        {
            var_dump($_REQUEST['test']);
            echo '<br ><br >';
            var_dump(urldecode($this->input->post('test', FALSE)));
            echo '<br ><br >';
            var_dump(rawurldecode($this->input->post('test', FALSE)));

        }
        else
        {
            echo form_open('home/test');
            echo form_hidden('test',"1bcw1kHHf0yTi8N%2bQGpdvsn4i7y3p2h1YAJnKy1QMS4iEgUQESIQEnSl");
            echo form_submit();
            echo form_close();
        }
}
```

Output:

```
Code igniter 2: (Notice the in the 2nd one there is NOT a "+" sign)

string(58) "1bcw1kHHf0yTi8N%2bQGpdvsn4i7y3p2h1YAJnKy1QMS4iEgUQESIQEnSl" 

string(56) "1bcw1kHHf0yTi8N QGpdvsn4i7y3p2h1YAJnKy1QMS4iEgUQESIQEnSl" 

string(56) "1bcw1kHHf0yTi8N+QGpdvsn4i7y3p2h1YAJnKy1QMS4iEgUQESIQEnSl"

Code igniter 3: (Works as expected)

string(58) "1bcw1kHHf0yTi8N%2bQGpdvsn4i7y3p2h1YAJnKy1QMS4iEgUQESIQEnSl" 

string(56) "1bcw1kHHf0yTi8N+QGpdvsn4i7y3p2h1YAJnKy1QMS4iEgUQESIQEnSl" 

string(56) "1bcw1kHHf0yTi8N+QGpdvsn4i7y3p2h1YAJnKy1QMS4iEgUQESIQEnSl"
```

Comment: what about this `urlencode(base64_encode());`

Comment: I am not sure how encoding it in base64  would help